# Как выводить данные из таблиц с помощью foreign | laravel

Tags: laravel

Есть две таблицы, связанные с помощью foreign, как в laravel, выводить данные из таблицы, которая связана с этой? Я новичок по этому если можно коротко рассказать весь механизм, если нужны какие-то данные для более понятного объяснение проблемы, пишите, всё предоставлю.

Comment: пройдите бесплатные официальные курсы по фреймворку. Есть даже с русскими субтитрами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов связи бывает несколько вот три из них самые распространенные.

[По данной ссылке](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships)  более подробное описание

[Русский вариант](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-relationships) не забывайте русская дока для пятой версии Лары.

**Один к одному**

в модели User:

```
public function phone()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
  }
```

в коде:

```
$phone = User::find(1)->phone;
```

**Один ко многим**

в модели post:

```
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
```

в коде:

```
$comments = App\Post::find(1)->comments;

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    //
}
```

**Один ко многим в обратную сторону**

в модели Comment :

```
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
```

в коде:

```
$comment = App\Comment::find(1);

echo $comment->post->title;
```

**Многие ко многим**

в модели post User:

```
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
```

в коде:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    //
}
```

Comment: А что такое App\Role, App\Post и т.д. Как эти классы сделать для работы с бд?

Comment: Это Классы модели. Сделать их можно с помощью команды php artisan make:model Role. Читайте информацию по паттерну MVC.